# Is there a way to make a package-like hierarchy for layout xml file in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to make a package-like hierarchy for layout xml files in android?

Android Fragment, Activity, Custom view class files can be in some package hierarchy and We can make their access to package private.

But, layout xml files are not. They are just in flat layout directory.

Is there anybody who knows why layout files dose not have package-like hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any way to make package hierarchy for layout xml files. In the same module, the best way to separate files is by naming. Activity files are going like `activity_`, and fragment files are going like `framgent_`.
It's hard to separate files by naming in **single** module. If you use **multi** module, there won't be many xml files in each modules.

If you have any more quesiton, please comment.